# Determining when GWTP place gets loaded completely

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform, gwtp

I use GWT + GWTP in my application. I have some places with nested presenters. I would like to execute some code after loading of a place (after place reveal is complete with all of contents and server calls, alongwith all nested presenters). Scheduling deferred or finally command does not work and gets called before place load is complete. 
Is there any way to detect the completion of revealing of place?

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be waiting for a number of server calls to complete, I suggest you send an event through the EventBus upon completion of your server calls. The root presenter in your presenter hierarchy will subscribe to those events. Once all required events have been received by the root presenter, you'll know that all server calls have ended.